FlChart, dynamically size through flexible; RenderBox Not Laid Out
Trying to automatically size a graph based with Flexible, problem is, no matter what I do I eventually end up with RenderBox Not Laid Out. I don't want to give it a fixed size nor size it through mediaqueries. Shouldn't flexible give the graph a constraint?
  Flexible(
                fit: FlexFit.loose,
                flex: 5,
                child: controller.user.dailyTarget == 0
                    ? PouchTimer(borderRadius: borderRadius)
                    : StatCard(
                        radius: borderRadius,
                        content: Expanded(
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 400,
                            child: FutureBuilder(
                                future: statisticsController.init,
                                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                    final List<FlSpot> pouchData =
                                        statisticsController
                                            .getPouchesLast(15);
                                    final double highestAmount = pouchData
                                        .reduce((current, next) =>
                                            current.y > next.y
                                                ? current
                                                : next)
                                        .y;

                                    return BarChart(
                                      BarChartData(
                                          extraLinesData: ExtraLinesData(
                                              horizontalLines: [
                                                HorizontalLine(
                                                    strokeCap:
                                                        StrokeCap.round,
                                                    dashArray: [4, 8],
                                                    label: HorizontalLineLabel(
                                                        alignment: Alignment
                                                            .topRight,
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Colors
                                                                .orange
                                                                .withOpacity(
                                                                    0.8)),
                                                        labelResolver:
                                                            (p0) =>
                                                                "Target",
                                                        show: true),
                                                    color: Colors.orange
                                                        .withOpacity(0.8),
                                                    y: controller
                                                        .user.dailyTarget
                                                        .toDouble()),
                                                HorizontalLine(
                                                    strokeCap:
                                                        StrokeCap.round,
                                                    dashArray: [4, 8],
                                                    label: HorizontalLineLabel(
                                                        alignment: Alignment
                                                            .topRight,
                                                        style:
                                                            const TextStyle(
                                                                color: Colors
                                                                    .grey),
                                                        labelResolver:
                                                            (p0) =>
                                                                "Past Usage",
                                                        show: true),
                                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                                    y: controller
                                                        .user.dailyUsage
                                                        .toDouble())
                                              ]),
                                          alignment:
                                              BarChartAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                          maxY: highestAmount >
                                                  controller.user.dailyUsage
                                              ? highestAmount
                                              : controller.user.dailyUsage
                                                  .toDouble(), // Adjust maxY dynamically based on the highest value
                                          titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                                            show: true,
                                            topTitles: const AxisTitles(
                                                sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                                    showTitles: false)),
                                            bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                                              axisNameSize: 12,
                                              sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                                reservedSize: 17,
                                                showTitles: true,
                                                getTitlesWidget:
                                                    (double value,
                                                        TitleMeta meta) {
                                                  // Format days for the last 30 days
                                                  final dayIndex =
                                                      value.toInt();
                                                  final DateTime today =
                                                      DateTime.now();
                                                  final DateTime date = today
                                                      .subtract(Duration(
                                                          days: dayIndex));

                                                  return Text(
                                                    date.day ==
                                                            DateTime.now()
                                                                .day
                                                        ? "Today"
                                                        : "",
                                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 12),
                                                  );
                                                },
                                                interval:
                                                    1, // Show every day
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                            leftTitles: const AxisTitles(
                                                sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                                    showTitles: false)),
                                            rightTitles: const AxisTitles(
                                              sideTitles: SideTitles(
                                                  reservedSize: 0,
                                                  showTitles: false,
                                                  interval: 20),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          gridData:
                                              const FlGridData(show: false),
                                          borderData:
                                              FlBorderData(show: false),
                                          barGroups: pouchData
                                              .asMap()
                                              .entries
                                              .map((entry) {
                                            final int index = entry.key;
                                            final double barHeight =
                                                entry.value.y;

                                            return BarChartGroupData(
                                              x: index,
                                              barRods: [
                                                BarChartRodData(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius
                                                            .circular(4),
                                                    toY: barHeight,
                                                    width: 20,
                                                    color: colorScheme
                                                        .primary),
                                              ],
                                            );
                                          }).toList()),
                                    );
                                  } else {
                                    return const Center(
                                        child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                                  }
                                }),
                          ),
                        ),
                        title:
                            "${controller.user.getMappedProductName(plural: true)} per day",
                      )),

Statcard:
class StatCard extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget content;
  String title;
  double radius;
  StatCard(
      {super.key,
      required this.content,
      required this.title,
      this.radius = 12});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius)),
      child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              Text(
                title,
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headlineSmall!
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 15),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              content,
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
}

